# How to use select statement to query only negative value in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
table_a 

billno    desc        qty    amount
10324    orange       -1     -1.00
10324    apple         1      3.00
10324    papaya        1      2.00

10431    water melon   1      2.00
10431    kiwi          1      3.00   

10233    banana       -1     -2.50
10233    mango         1      4.00
..
.. 
total 378 records
```

Hi, how to use select statement query desc,qty and amount have negative qty in the billno, if i don't know the billno ?

I had tried use sign(number) syntax, but result incorrect.

```
select desc,qty,amount from table_a where sign(qty)='-1';
orange       -1     -1.00
banana       -1     -2.50
```

my goal

```
orange       -1     -1.00
apple         1      3.00
papaya        1      2.00  

banana       -1     -2.50
mango         1      4.00
```

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where exists (select 1 from table_a b where a.bill_no =b.bill_no and b.qty <0). Ensuring the original from aliases the table as a

Comment: Why is e.g. "apple" whose QTY = 1 in your "goal"? It doesn't have negative QTY.

Comment: Just get rid of quotes such as `sign(qty)=-1`

Comment: @Littefoot because I want only billno content desc have negative value even have other desc as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to look in the same table for the same `billno` to see if there are any items with a negative quantity

```sql
WITH
    table_a (billno,
             item_desc,
             qty,
             amount)
    AS
        (SELECT 10324, 'orange', -1, -1.00 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10324, 'apple', 1, 3.00 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10324, 'papaya', 1, 2.00 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10431, 'water melon', 1, 2.00 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10431, 'kiwi', 1, 3.00 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10233, 'banana', -1, -2.50 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10233, 'mango', 1, 4.00 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM table_a a1
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM table_a a2
             WHERE a2.billno = a1.billno AND a2.qty < 0)
```

Comment: Hi @EJ Egyed your code is work for me, thank you very much. :)